Scraping the hulkapps table using Selenium or Beautiful soup
I have this URL that I am trying to scrape: https://papemelroti.com/products/live-free-badge
But it seems that I can't find this table class
<table class="hulkapps-table table"><thead><tr><th style="border-top-left-radius: 0px;">Quantity</th><th style="border-top-right-radius: 0px;">Bulk Discount</th><th style="display: none">Add to Cart</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;">Buy 50 +   <span class="hulk-offer-text"></span></td><td style="border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;"><span class="hulkapps-price"><span class="money"><span class="money"> ₱1.00 </span></span> Off</span></td><td style="display: none;"><button type="button" class="AddToCart_0" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: .08em; font-size: 11px; padding: 5px 15px; border-color: #171515; border-width: 2px; color: #ffffff; background: #161212;" onclick="add_to_cart(50)">Add to Cart</button></td></tr></tbody></table>

I already have my Selenium code but it's still not scraping it. Here's my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Adjust path if necessary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

def get_page_html(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)  # Wait for JS to load
    return driver.page_source

def scrape_discount_quantity(url):
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

    # Locate the table containing the quantity and discount
    table = soup.find('table', class_='hulkapps-table')
    print(page_html)

    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in table_rows:
            quantity_cells = row.find_all('td')
            if len(quantity_cells) >= 2:  # Check if there are at least two cells
                quantity_cell = quantity_cells[0].get_text(strip=True)  # Get quantity text
                discount_cell = quantity_cells[1].get_text(strip=True)  # Get discount text
                return quantity_cell, discount_cell
    return None, None

# Example usage
url = 'https://papemelroti.com/products/live-free-badge'
quantity, discount = scrape_discount_quantity(url)
print(f"Quantity: {quantity}, Discount: {discount}")

driver.quit()  # Close the browser when done

It keeps on returning 'None'
For reference:


Discount Data loaded from this https://volumediscount.hulkapps.com/api/v2/shop/get_offer_table API endpoint, bs4 didn't have that table name to scrape when you returned the page source by using selenium driver.page_source, I tried your code and confirmed that hulkapps-table didn't exist in the response! so it's obvious response will be None,
My answer:
I used this https://volumediscount.hulkapps.com/api/v2/shop/get_offer_table API endpoint along with product_id from this request https://papemelroti.com/products/live-free-badge.json, here is my code and it's basic:
import requests
import json

def getDiscount(root_url):
    prod_resp = requests.get(f'{root_url}.json').content #Get product_id
    prod_id = json.loads(prod_resp)['product']['id']
    disc_url = 'https://volumediscount.hulkapps.com/api/v2/shop/get_offer_table' #Discount URL
    data = f'pid={prod_id}&store_id=papemelroti.myshopify.com'
    headers = {
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0",
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    }
    resp = requests.post(disc_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    disc_json = json.loads(resp.json()['eligible_offer']['offer_levels'])[0]
    
    #Offer has two variants: 'Price' and 'Off' so you can use condition if you like to scrape products other than 'live-free-badge'

    if 'price_discount' in disc_json[2]:
        print(f"Product ID:{prod_id} (Quantity: {disc_json[0]}, Discount: {disc_json[1]} Price discount)")
    elif 'Off' in disc_json[2]:
        print(f"Product ID:{prod_id} (Quantity: {disc_json[0]}, Discount: {disc_json[1]}% Off)")

#sample for both 'Off' and 'Price'
getDiscount('https://papemelroti.com/products/dear-me-magnet')
getDiscount('https://papemelroti.com/products/live-free-badge')

Output:
Product ID:7217967726790 (Quantity: 50, Discount: 10% Off)
Product ID:104213217289 (Quantity: 50, Discount: 1.00 Price discount)

Let me know if this is ok or if you want to be strict with selenium

Wow. Didn't notice the API. Will have this implemented and will accept your answer once it works. Thanks!
